# Find a general solution for gravitational potential, $\Phi(r)$ in a uniform, Newtonian universe, to derive Friedmann equations with $v_r = rH(t)$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, cosmology

I want to derive the Friedmann equation in a Newtonian regime, but properly.
So, I am supposed to consider a cold fluid with density $\rho$, velocity field $v$ and gravitational potential $\Phi$. By cold, I mean that it has no thermal velocities. At each position in space, it has a density $\rho(\mathbf{x})$ and velocity field $\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})$.

We have

$$\dot{\rho} + \nabla \cdot \left(\rho \mathbb{v} \right) =0$$
$$\dot{\mathbb{v}} + \left(\mathbb{v}\cdot \nabla \right)\mathbb{v}= -\nabla \Phi$$
$$\nabla^2 \Phi = 4 \pi G \rho $$

I derived the three equations above, and they fully specify the system. Consider solutions of the kind $\rho=\rho(t)$ and $\mathbf{v} = v_r(r,t)\hat{r}$.

My work is shown below. I know it's wrong as gravitational potential can not be zero everywhere (I think?), but from the right solution to this problem I am supposed to use the ansatz $v_r = r H(t)$ to derive the Friedmann equation. I think that I perhaps applied Green's function wrong by generalizing it to one dimension, but I didn't really understand that part conceptually well enough to explain my exact thought processes - I just tried to math it out. How can I first obtain $\Phi(r)$? Thank you for any help!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Similar work has been done here: https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9510056v3

Comment: Too long way to get simple answer $\Phi =2\pi G\rho (t) r^2/3$ :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev, could you please show me how you got the answer? Thanks for the solution, though I’m not sure how to get to it.

Comment: Just put in equation $\nabla ^2\Phi =4\pi G\rho(t)$ solution $\Phi = \phi_0 (x^2+y^2+z^2)$ and take into account that $\nabla ^2 (x^2+y^2+z^2)=6$.

Comment: @AlexTrounev how do you know the solution $\Phi = \Phi_0 (x^2+y^2+z^2)$?

Comment: This is solution of the Poisson's equation with constant in space density. But what a doubt do you have?